# npm run serve not working on Vue Project "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type"

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack, vue-cli

It's happened on my current project then I try to delete node_modules and install it again but it doesn't work anyway
and I try to create a new one using

```
vue create "newproject"
```

to make sure that have no anythings wrong with my code
on my vue-cli version

> @vue/cli 4.5.7

and I try to start a new one by

```
npm run serve
```

but the error is still appear

```
> newproject@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                           12:40:11 PM

 error  in ./node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (763:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| }
| class RefImpl {
>     _rawValue;
|     _shallow;
|     _value;

 @ ./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js 1:0-233 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 16:4-17 40:4-17 107:13-18 108:32-37 115:16-21 1958:8-13 1962:13-23 1968:35-45 1970:16-21 1973:21-31 2071:19-25 2094:8-12 2135:8-13 2210:29-34 2557:27-30 2558:26-29 2559:28-31 2905:16-29 2912:16-29 3043:28-36 3362:41-56 3378:28-33 3463:8-15 3500:32-37 3647:27-32 3823:29-34 3951:12-25 3958:12-25 4568:17-22 4592:13-18 5173:26-32 5336:8-21 5340:8-21 5755:16-20 5761:12-16 6296:27-32 6328:12-19 6338:16-23 6356:93-100 6357:15-20 6767:60-75 6768:60-75 6769:60-75 6770:59-74 6847:16-21 6997:16-21 7150:21-28 7160:8-21 7161:134-149 7162:8-21 7210:30-39 7264:8-21 7266:8-21 7314:23-38 7334:46-55 7334:56-63 7389:14-24 7576:21-26 7586:21-31 7593:24-34 7596:21-31 7624:53-58 7630:52-57 7696:48-53
 @ ./node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js
 @ ./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.218:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

my new project package.json

```json
{
  "name": "newproject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

vue.config.js

transpileDependencies: ['@vue/reactivity'],

is OK